# bash: /usr/local/sphinx/bin/search: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sphinx

I'm installing Sphinx 2.2.4 from the source on an Ubuntu server. I ran ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ and when trying to actually check my index I get the above error. I see that the file doesn't exist. How is this script created? Did I not include the right option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search` is no longer provided by sphinx.

it had become neglected and broken, so using it you couldn't tell if the tool was broken, or the index. So to reduce confuison it was was removed.

The documentation you following must be outdated.

Can use `indextool` to run a few quick sanity checks on a index, but its often easier to just got right ahead and try loading the index into the real `searchd` daemon.

Comment: " but its often easier to just got right ahead and try loading the index into the real searchd daemon". How can I do this?

Comment: Surely the instructions must cover that? It was always the eventual goal anyway. `search` was just a quick testing tool, not a critial part of the process. searchd is what is used for serving real queries.